# Installing Tensorflow on Docker with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, raspberry-pi3

I want to install Tensorflow v1.12.0 on a Docker-container which is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B Plus using a Dockerfile from python:3.6-slim.
I am aware that i need to take into account that im using an armv7l architecture.

So far I tried installing with pip/pip3 with and without information about version and with and without the use of my requirements.txt.
This way all other needed packages can be installed with pip.
But I am getting the Error:

```
Step 5/13 : RUN pip install tensorflow==1.12.0
             ---> Running in d0ecb01c7fbc
            Collecting tensorflow==1.12.0
              Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0 (from versions: )
            No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0
            The command '/bin/bash -c pip install tensorflow==1.12.0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Then I tried installing with the armv7l miniconda. But it seems the Tensorflow package is not supported with that version of miniconda.

Lastly I tried installing from a precompiled wheel for arm from this repo: https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases.
Like so: `RUN pip install https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.12.0/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl`
Here I changed to python:3.5-slim which starts out fine but seems to stop somewhere and results in a broken pipe (I am doing this remote).

I dont know what I could try next and didn't find anything else online.

Comment: I have build a docker image with optimized TensorFlow for RPi couple years ago, you can try it: https://hub.docker.com/r/dprylipko/tf-neon-vfpv4. But the TF version is quite old now, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have the v1.12.0. May I ask how you made it?

Comment: I followed Makefile instructions for Raspberry Pi: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile#raspberry-pi

Comment: Upon which Image did you build the container you compiled it in?

Comment: I don't remember :( Probably, no basic image. I did not even used a docker file, just installed basic dependencies on the system and compiled/installed TF inside a docker container.